# how to use html in a material-ui Snackbar message

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying (react) material-ui in my application. It's is something like the example in the docs:

```
function MySnackbarContentWrapper(props) {
    const classes = useStyles1();
    const { className, message, variant, ...other } = props;
    const Icon = variantIcon[variant];

    return (
        <SnackbarContent
            className={clsx(classes[variant], className)}
            aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
            message={
                <span id="client-snackbar" className={classes.message}>
                    <Icon className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.iconVariant)} />
                    {message}
                </span>
            }
            action={[
                <IconButton key="close" aria-label="Close" color="inherit" onClick={props.close}>
                    <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
                </IconButton>,
            ]}
            {...other}
        />
    );
}
```

Now, if my message text is: `<em><b>Hello</b></em>`, it just shows like that: `<em><b>Hello</b></em>`, and not like: ***Hello***.

Can somebody help me in achieving this?

When I used *angularjs* in the past, and I continue to use it now, I wrapped the text in an: `ng-bind-html="alert.msg | unsafe"`. Now, I don't now how to do that in material-ui.

Many thanks and bye ...

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox with your issue ?

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Ryan: thanks for the info about _dangerouslySetInnerHTML_; didn't know about that, really. It's very powerful although we should exert some care. Thanks again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the message as just text like "Hello" and provide the italics and bold styles with css to the spans

```
.spanClass{
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```